Sheepit missing video textures
I am using an mp4 as a video texture in my blend file. I don't have any issues with any other of my textures only the mp4. When I try to upload my file to sheepit I get the following messages. I have attached some images so you may understand my problem.


I have read online that maybe Blender doesn't support the packing of mp4 videos. I have found a work around this in the past. I just cant remember how I manage to upload a blend file that uses an mp4 as a texture.

Yeah, it does seem like video files can't be packed, according to the docs. Maybe converting the MP4 to a image sequence might do the trick?

Can't you upload zip files to sheepit, containing the video alongside the blend file correctly mapped in the blend file?

Suggest you ask Sheepit since it doesn't have anything to do with Blender!

What you have read online is true, you cannot pack videos into a blend file. Apart from that I agree with @JohnEason that it's not really a Blender problem.
